# How to print the current source line in windbg?

Tags: windbg

I was wondering if it's possible to display the current source line in windbg?

Right now I am able to step through the code and display 5 lines before and after the current line every time I step through the code. This is great, but it would be nice if there was a command to print the current source line on demand instead of having to step to the next line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you  want to print a single source line use **[lsp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/lsp--set-number-of-source-lines-)**
The default value is 20 (0x14)

```
> lsp -a 1
WARNING: Source line display is disabled
At the prompt, display 0 source lines before and 1 after
For lsa commands, display 0 source lines before
For ls and lsa commands, display 1 source lines
```

now use [lsa](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/ls--lsa--list-source-lines-)  where .denotes the current Eip/Rip

```
0:000:x86> lsa .
>   28: void main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
```

or provide an address

```
0:000:x86> lsa @$ip+42
>   30:     SymInitialize(hProcess, NULL, FALSE);
```

you  can also provide the source line to lsa

```
0:000> lsa `symtype!symtype.cpp:16`
>   16:     if (maxcmplen == pSymInfo->NameLen) {
0:000> lsa `symtype!symtype.cpp:28`
>   28: void main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
```